# MFMailComposeViewController gets exited while using in ipad and works fine in simulator

Tags: xcode

I am using this code and settings are provided to check whether mail account is set or not. But when it reaches the `NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"feedback@xyz"];`
it gets aborted. My code is given below. `MessageUI.framework` is also provided fine.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"heading"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"some text" isHTML:NO];
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"feedback@xyz"]; 
[controller setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Comment: comment this line and try again [controller setToRecipients:toRecipients];

Comment: let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: @Hitman: yes then it works well....

Comment: Look at the answer.There I have explained in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recipient email address is not valid.That's why problem occurred. Use this:

```
@"feedback@gmail.com"
```

Comment: when i comment those lines it working.. else aborting from that point. i didn't launch it so i dont know whether its working or not.

Comment: give a valid email like abc@gmail.com like this

Comment: did you get it or not?I have checked this.It is working fine at me